# Trigger a button when the user click in Enter button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger a button click when the user presses in the Enter button inside an input. I tried to do this, but without any success. Here's my attempt:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exercice 1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function key() {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById('btn').click()
      }

      function test() {
        alert('okay');
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write your word" onkeydown="key()" />
  </form>
  <button id="btn" onClick="test()">test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the goal to get it to alert? Just call the function that does the alert

Comment: Is there a reason the button inside the form? This way you can listen to the submit event.

Comment: Everything seems right. Have you checked the syntax?

Comment: @Ju66ernaut, no the code has a lot of function, but I want just to fix the function problem

Comment: @pcbabu if you try the code, it not work :'(

Comment: @saadsaad I know how JS error feels. But these are not done like this way. Why you should fire an event like: one button click actually clicks another one? Simply create another common function. In both button call that function.

Comment: @pcbabu There are actually very valid reasons to trigger an event, rather than just invoke a callback. If you trigger the event, you can leverage bubbling/capturing, which you can't do if you just call a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. **You were just missing a closing curly brace afer your `if` statement.**

```js
// Modern browsers send an event object to the event
// callback function
function key(evt){
  // But, older versions of IE expose the event as a property
  // of the window object, so let's make sure we have a good
  // reference to it:
  evt = evt || window.event;

  // Getting the key code has never been standardized
  if (evt.which === 13){
    document.getElementById('btn').click();
  } // <-- You were missing this.
}
         
function test(){
  alert('okay');
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Write your word" onkeydown = "key()"/>
</form>
<button id="btn" onClick="test()">test</button>
```

And, we really should avoid inline HTML event handling as it violates the separation of concerns between HTML and JavaScript, it causes a global anonymous proxy function to be created that modifies `this` binding in the callback and doesn't leverage the modern [W3C DOM Level 2 Event Handling standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)

Here's the modern way to hook event handlers up:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  var txt = document.getElementById("txtInput");
  
  btn.addEventListener("click", test);
  txt.addEventListener("keydown", key);

    // Modern browsers send an event object to the event
    // callback function
    function key(evt){
      // But, older versions of IE expose the event as a property
      // of the window object, so let's make sure we have a good
      // reference to it:
      evt = evt || window.event;

      console.log("Callback function invoked by: " + evt.target);
      console.log("Key pressed was: " + evt.which);      
      
      // Getting the key code has never been standardized until 
      // fairly recently. event.which is the recommended approach
      if (evt.which === 13){
        document.getElementById('btn').click();
      } // <-- You were missing this.
    }
             
    function test(){
      alert('okay');
    }
  
});
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="txtInput" placeholder="Write your word">
 <button id="btn">test</button>
```

Comment: Also, the `key` function should take an `event` argumant and test if `(event || window.event).keyCode == 13` to be compatible with most browsers (I think global event is IE only)

Comment: True. And, if we're going down that road. We should use `event.which` instead of `keyCode`. But, the issue at hand is just the missing curly brace.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The problem with this is that your snippet fails with a `ReferenceError` when a key is pressed. **Edit: nevermind**

Comment: @RyanZim This code works perfectly. There is no error.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

      var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      var txt = document.getElementById("txtInput");

      btn.addEventListener("click", test);
      txt.addEventListener("keydown", key);

function key(evt){

      evt = evt || window.event;

      if (evt.which === 13){
        document.getElementById('btn').click();
      }
    }
});

 <input type="text" id="txtInput" placeholder="Write your word">
 <button id="btn">test</button>
```

Your code doesn't work because your missing a bracket after the **if** statement.Also i hope my code will help you.

Comment: While this may work, it uses JQuery, which the OP wasn't asking about. It also doesn't inform the OP of why his code didn't work.